# flag strings based on previous values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, window-functions

I would like to flag sentences located in a pandas dataframe. As you can see in the example, some of the sentences are split into multiple rows (these are subtitles from an srt file that I would like to translate to a different language eventually, but first I need to put them in a single cell). The end of the sentence is determined by the period at the end. I want to create a column like the column sentence, where I number each sentence (it doesn't have to be a string, it could be a number too)

```
values=[
        ['This is an example of subtitle.','sentence_1'],
        ['I want to group by sentences, which','sentence_2'],
        ['the end is determined by a period.','sentence_2'],
        ['row 0 should have sentece_1, rows 1 and 2 ','sentence_3'],
        ['should have sentence_2.','sentence_2'],
        ['and this last row should have sentence_3.','sentence_3']
        ]
df=pd.DataFrame(values,columns=['subtitle','sentence_number'])
df['presence_of_period']=df.subtitle.str.contains('\.')
df

output:

    subtitle                                         sentence_number    presence_of_period
0   This is an example of subtitle.                  sentence_1         True
1   I want to group by sentences, which              sentence_2         False
2   the end is determined by a period.               sentence_2         True
3   row 0 should have sentece_1, rows 1 and 2        sentence_3         False
4   should have sentence_2. and this                 sentence_3         True
5   last row should have sentence_3.                 sentence_4         True
```

How can I create the sentence_number column since it has to read the previous cells on subtitle column? I was thinking of a window function or the shift() but couldn't figure out how to make it work. I added a column to show if the cell has a period, signifying the end of the sentence. Also, if possible, I would like to move the "and this" from row 4 to the beginning of row 5, since it is a new sentence (not sure if this one would require a different question).

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the sentence number, here's an option for you.

```
import pandas as pd
values=[
        ['This is an example of subtitle.','sentence_1'],
        ['I want to group by sentences, which','sentence_2'],
        ['the end is determined by a period.','sentence_2'],
        ['row 0 should have sentece_1, rows 1 and 2 ','sentence_3'],
        ['should have sentence_2.','sentence_2'],
        ['and this last row should have sentence_3.','sentence_3']
        ]
df=pd.DataFrame(values,columns=['subtitle','sentence_number'])
df['presence_of_period']=df.subtitle.str.count('\.')
df['end'] = df.subtitle.str.endswith('.').astype(int)
df['sentence_#'] = 'sentence_' + (1 + df['presence_of_period'].cumsum() - df['end']).astype(str)
#print (df['subtitle'])
#print (df[['sentence_number','presence_of_period','end','sentence_#']])
df.drop(['presence_of_period','end'],axis=1, inplace=True)
print (df[['subtitle','sentence_#']])
```

The output will be as follows:

```
                                     subtitle  sentence_#
0             This is an example of subtitle.  sentence_1
1         I want to group by sentences, which  sentence_2
2          the end is determined by a period.  sentence_2
3  row 0 should have sentece_1, rows 1 and 2   sentence_3
4                     should have sentence_2.  sentence_3
5   and this last row should have sentence_3.  sentence_4
```

If you need to move the partial sentence to the next row, I need to understand a bit more details.

What do you want to do if there are more than two sentences in a row. For example, `'This is first sentence. This second. This is'`.

What do you want to do in this case. Split the first one to a row, second to another row, and concatenate the third to the next row data?

Once I understand this, we can use the `df.explode()` to solve it.

Comment: Wow, this is great. Thank you. I didn't think of the scenario with 2 dots. I guess in that case I would like to have each sentence in its own row:
'This is the first sentence'
'This second'
'This third'.

I guess I should also be careful with the scenario of having words such as '12.5 percent'  which the period could trigger the end of the sentence when it is not.

Comment: @chulo, I was going to ask the same thing next. How will you differentiate between a period and a float or something like `www.google.com`. This will have multiple periods. Should it be end of a word? If so, then we may have to use regex `\.\b` A lot of things need to be figured out before we can finalize the solution. That's why I didn't lock the solution. Lots to be flushed out

Comment: I think for now I would feel comfortable if the period has a space after that then it should be considered end of sentence, otherwise it should be ignored because it is part of the string. I know sometimes you encounter the "this is sentence1.this is sentence 2" scenario but it will be rare in my dataset I think.